# Generate and fill 2 dimensional array with Numpy

Tags: python, arrays, csv, numpy, multidimensional-array

I would like to generate a 2 dimensional array with NumPy , iterate some variable few times, and fill the 2 dimensional array with 2 pieces of `float` data that gets calculated inside the `for` iteration. Then export it out to `.csv`

Technically I would like to do it like this:

```
max_array=8000
ARRAY=numpy.zeros(  [max_array*2]   , dtype=float)
ARRAY=numpy.arange(max_array*2).reshape((max_array,2))

for i in range(1,max_array):
######calculations here#######
 array[i,i]=[data1,data2]

numpy.savetxt("output.csv", numpy.asarray(ARRAY), delimiter=",")
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work, I am very clumsy with syntax, and probably the [,] brackets are the problem. I would be very thankful if somebody would fix my snippet.

Comment: what error does it give you?

Comment: @Astrom it gives this error if I run it like this "ValueError: total size of new array must be unchanged", it is probably the brackets that are not correctly used

Comment: You don't need both `ARRAY` assignments.  What is `array` (lower case name)?  Why 2 values for one slot?

Comment: Please post the Traceback.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
max_array = 4
ARRAY = np.arange(max_array*2).reshape((max_array,2))
```

You have created a 2-d array

```
>>> ARRAY
array([[0, 1],
       [2, 3],
       [4, 5],
       [6, 7]])
>>>
```

`ARRAY[i,i]` indexes a single element in the array

```
>>> i = 0
>>> ARRAY[i,i]
0
>>> ARRAY[i,i] = 222
>>> ARRAY
array([[222,   1],
       [  2,   3],
       [  4,   5],
       [  6,   7]])
```

If you want to assign values to a row:

```
>>> ARRAY[0] = 99, 99
>>> ARRAY
array([[99, 99],
       [ 2,  3],
       [ 4,  5],
       [ 6,  7]])
```

Or

```
>>> ARRAY[2,:] = 66, 66
>>> ARRAY
array([[99, 99],
       [ 2,  3],
       [66, 66],
       [ 6,  7]])
```

The second value in the *subscript* indexes a column

```
>>> ARRAY[:, 1]
array([99,  3, 66,  7])

>>> ARRAY[:, 1] = 0
>>> ARRAY
array([[99,  0],
       [ 2,  0],
       [66,  0],
       [ 6,  0]])
>>>
```

---

`ARRAY[i,i] = data1, data2` : tries to assign two things to a single element in the array - that is why you get an error.

---

Numpy docs
[Indexing, Slicing, Iterating](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/quickstart.html#indexing-slicing-and-iterating)
[Indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html#indexing)

Comment: That last line would give a `ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.`

Comment: That only works for integers, i need a `float` array

Comment: @PiNewbie, not sure I understand your comment - ```ARRAY=numpy.arange(max_array*2).reshape((max_array,2))``` was taken from your example code - it produces an integer array.  Indexing works the same regardless of the array type.

Comment: @hpaulj - yea, I noticed that, doesn't actually jive with OP's stated error.??